# Wordpress filtering with URL and meta_key

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url, filter

I have made a javascript script that adds all selected tags, colours and categories to a list, which is then added to the href attribute of a URL in a Wordpress theme so it searches for it. This all works like a breeze producing good results, and a URL like so wordpress/?tag=flat+dark&colours=A0F200+FFFFFF&category_name=print . However when I want to order posts by meta_key, the meta_key attribute is private so cannot appear in url, as set by wordpress so therefore cannot be searched. SO I attempt to add a query posts tag including only the meta_key tag, like so

```
<?php  

query_posts( 'meta_key=_post_like_count' );
?>
```

but this prevents the filtering of other things such as tags and colours, so ruins my whole search ideal...

Does anyone know of a way to get around this, set a query that does not limit url querying or somehow make meta_key filtering not private?